# Pass type token as parameter for a generic method

Tags: java, generics, cdi, typetoken

I have a method on a (CDI) service class that looks something similar to this;

```
@Named
public class PreferenceService {
    public <T extends AbstractType> T getPreferenceValue(String prefCode, T t){
        List<PreferenceValue> prefs = /* code that gets list from db*/
        return prefs.get(0).getTypedValue(t);
    }
}
```

getTypedValue() has been defined as

```
public <T extends AbstractType> T getTypedValue(T t) {
    t.instantiateFromString(getValue());
    return t;
}
```

Edit: Values, the 'value' returned by 'getValue()' in the above code are basically strings. Given a type 'instantiateFromString()' does a casting/parsing of some sort to return the correct typed value.

Edit2: 
Meanwhile, StringType is a custom type that inherits from AbstractType with implementations on instantiation, and value casting/coercion

Now, i'd like the caller of the preferenceService bean to be called in the following manner

```
preferenceService.getPreferenceValue("pref.code", StringType.class);
```

where StringType is type token to be used in getting the desired value. Is this even possible? Thanks!

Comment: Since `StringType` is a subclass of `ImmutableType`, have you considered accepting `ImmutableType` as an argument?  (or AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<T>).

Comment: @Nicholas, see Edit2 above

Comment: Solved! preferenceService.getPreferenceValue("pref.code", new StringType());